# TeXForm doesn't work in wolframscript?

Tags: formatting, scripting, conversion

Consider that

```
$ wolframscript -cloud -code 'TeXForm[ (d u)/(d t)]'
TeXForm[u/t]
```

yet

> [image]

I don't have a local wolframscript kernel installed. Is this something that only works for a local kernel?

Comment: Actually in your expression d is a variable and mathematica would automatically simplify it, hence the \frac{u}{t} result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't check how formatting works in wolframscript but if you force it on your terms then it does not matter:

TL;DR: use:

> $ wolframscript -cloud -code 'ToString @ TeXForm[ (d u)/(d t)]'

[image]

Comment: Ok. So a good rule of thumb is to always parse output as a string when things aren't displaying properly.